# PyQGIS 3 Single user shapefile editing for network drive

Tags: qgis, python, shapefile, qgis-3, pyqgis-3

I have a project saved on a shared network drive, with a group of people working on it. I need a PyQGIS solution to prevent multiple users from editing the same shapefile. That is, once one of the users has switched a layer into 'edit mode', other users should not be able to do the same until they have disabled edit mode and saved their changes, so as not to overwrite each others' changes. A simple script would suffice, I will then code it into a QGIS plugin.

Comment: What have you tried already? If you provide some code and are more specific about where you are stuck, you will likely get some better responses.

Comment: External locking to a networked shapefile is an iffy use case. You might want to explore using a PostgreSQL database to get true distributed editing.